# Java breadth-first search for finding the shortest path on a 2D grid with obstacles

Tags: java, algorithm, pathfinding, breadth-first-search

Please review my [Breadth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) algorithm implementation in Java for finding the shortest path on a 2D grid map with obstacles.

The `findPath()` method receives a map array of integers where `0` is an empty cell, and `1` is an obstacle, the function returns a list of coordinates which is the optimal path or `null` if such path does not exist.

*This code is not a thread-safe, I have no intention of making it such.*

```
 import java.util.LinkedList;
 import java.awt.Point;

/**
 * Created by Ilya Gazman on 10/17/2018.
 */
public class BFS {

    private static final boolean DEBUG = false;

    public Point[] findPath(int[][] map, Point position, Point destination) {
        if (isOutOfMap(map, position)) {
            return null;
        }
        if (isOutOfMap(map, destination)) {
            return null;
        }
        if (isBlocked(map, position)) {
            return null;
        }
        if (isBlocked(map, destination)) {
            return null;
        }
        LinkedList<Point> queue1 = new LinkedList<>();
        LinkedList<Point> queue2 = new LinkedList<>();

        queue1.add(position);
        map[position.y][position.x] = -1;
        int stepCount = 2;
        while (!queue1.isEmpty()) {
            if(queue1.size() >= map.length * map[0].length){
                throw new Error("Map overload");
            }
            for (Point point : queue1) {
                if (point.x == destination.x && point.y == destination.y) {
                    Point[] optimalPath = new Point[stepCount - 1];
                    computeSolution(map, point.x, point.y, stepCount - 1, optimalPath);
                    resetMap(map);
                    return optimalPath;
                }
                LinkedList<Point> finalQueue = queue2;
                int finalStepCount = stepCount;
                lookAround(map, point, (x, y) -> {
                    if (isBlocked(map, x, y)) {
                        return;
                    }
                    Point e = new Point(x, y);

                    finalQueue.add(e);
                    map[e.y][e.x] = -finalStepCount;
                });
            }

            if (DEBUG) {
                printMap(map);
            }

            queue1 = queue2;
            queue2 = new LinkedList<>();
            stepCount++;
        }
        resetMap(map);
        return null;
    }

    private void resetMap(int[][] map) {
        for (int y = 0; y < map.length; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < map[0].length; x++) {
                if (map[y][x] < 0) {
                    map[y][x] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean isBlocked(int[][] map, Point p) {
        return isBlocked(map, p.x, p.y);
    }

    private boolean isBlocked(int[][] map, int x, int y) {
        int i = map[y][x];
        return i < 0 || i == 1;
    }

    private void printMap(int[][] map) {
        //noinspection ForLoopReplaceableByForEach
        for (int i = 0, mapLength = map.length; i < mapLength; i++) {
            int[] aMap = map[i];
            for (int x = 0; x < map[0].length; x++) {
                System.out.print(aMap[x] + "\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println("****************************************");
    }

    private void computeSolution(int[][] map, int x, int y, int stepCount, Point[] optimalPath) {
        if (isOutOfMap(map, x, y) || map[y][x] == 0) {
            return;
        }

        if ( -stepCount != map[y][x]) {
            return;
        }

        Point p = new Point(x, y);
        optimalPath[stepCount - 1] = p;
        lookAround(map, p, (x1, y1) -> computeSolution(map, x1, y1, stepCount - 1, optimalPath));
    }

    private void lookAround(int[][] map, Point p, Callback callback) {
        callback.look(map, p.x + 1, p.y + 1);
        callback.look(map, p.x - 1, p.y + 1);
        callback.look(map, p.x - 1, p.y - 1);
        callback.look(map, p.x + 1, p.y - 1);
        callback.look(map, p.x + 1, p.y);
        callback.look(map, p.x - 1, p.y);
        callback.look(map, p.x, p.y + 1);
        callback.look(map, p.x, p.y - 1);
    }

    private static boolean isOutOfMap(int[][] map, Point p) {
        return isOutOfMap(map, p.x, p.y);
    }

    private static boolean isOutOfMap(int[][] map, int x, int y) {
        if (x < 0 || y < 0) {
            return true;
        }
        return map.length <= y || map[0].length <= x;
    }

    private interface Callback {
        default void look(int[][] map, int x, int y) {
            if (isOutOfMap(map, x, y)) {
                return;
            }
            onLook(x, y);
        }

        void onLook(int x, int y);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    int[][] myMap = {
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1},
            {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0},
    };

    Point[] path = new BFS().findPath(myMap, new Point(8, 0), new Point(8, 2));
    for (Point point : path) {
        System.out.println(point.x + ", " + point.y);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
8, 0
7, 0
6, 0
5, 0
4, 1
4, 2
5, 3
6, 2
7, 2
8, 2
```

Comment: Is this actually working?

Comment: @KrzysztofCichocki Yeah, it runs in `O(n)` where `n` is the number of nodes. It's a special case of the classic `O(v+e)` since my `e` is equal to 8 it becomes redundant.

Comment: @IlyaGazman Can you add an example of its usage? i.e. an example of proper inputs and what is expected as output.

Comment: @esote Sure, here you go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm unfamiliar with the algorithm. It looks neat, but I couldn't tell you if it's optimal or not. Most optimization comes from improving the way you go about the algorithm, so I'll suggest stuff for readability.

## Don't stutter

When you check `isOutOfMap()` for `position` and `destination`, there's no need to break them up into multiple if statements. Same goes for `isBlocked()`.

```java
if (isOutOfMap(map, position.x, position.y)
        || isOutOfMap(map, destination.x, destination.y)
        || isBlocked(map, position.x, position.y)
        || isBlocked(map, destination.x, destination.y)) {
    return null;
}
```

While we're at it, why have overloaded methods for `isOutOfMap()` and `isBlocked()`? The ultimate result is that you're avoiding directly accessing the `Point`'s parameters `x` and `y`.

I would remove `isOutofMap(int[][], Point)` and `isBlocked(int[][], Point)` and opt for directly passing the `Point`'s `x` and `y` coordinates.

## Use an `Exception`

Instead of throwing an `Error`, throw an `Exception`. You can't recover from an `Error`, it terminates program execution. Throw an `Exception`.

```java
throw new IllegalStateException("Map overload");
```

If you use `IllegalStateException` you won't need to add `throws`. I'd opt for the most specific exception type you can find, or make one yourself.

## Use the right loops

You've got `stepCount`, `while(!queue1.isEmpty())` and at the end `stepCount++`. That's a for loop. Rather than calling it `stepCount` (redundant), go with old faithful `i`. It's clear that you're counting with it.

## Decrease the complexity

`findPath()` is a pretty complex method. We should move some things to their own methods.

If we arrive at our destination, we can call the `arrived()` method:

```java
private Point[] arrived(int[][] map, int size, Point p) {
    Point[] optimalPath = new Point[size];

    computeSolution(map, p.x, p.y, size, optimalPath);

    resetMap(map);

    return optimalPath;
}
```

I'm sure there are other places to clean up, but you get my point.

## Use `final` where it makes sense

While others may disagree, I prefer annotating things as `final` when they are, in fact, `final`. This lets me know if I accidentially try to modify the value, when it shouldn't really be modified.

## Use the right structures

You're using `LinkedList` but calling it a queue. While it's true that `LinkedList` implements the `Queue` interface, as it goes:

> This class is likely to be faster than `Stack` when used as a stack and faster than `LinkedList` when used as a queue.
>
> *- [ArrayDeque](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html)*

So we'll trust them. Instead of using `LinkedList`, we can use an `ArrayDeque`.

## Code

Here's the code I ended up with. Hope this has helped.

```java
import java.awt.Point;
import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.Queue;

/**
 * Created by Ilya Gazman on 10/17/2018.
 */
public class BFS {

    private static final boolean DEBUG = false;

    public Point[] findPath(final int[][] map,
                            final Point position,
                            final Point destination) {
        if (isOutOfMap(map, position.x, position.y)
                || isOutOfMap(map, destination.x, destination.y)
                || isBlocked(map, position.x, position.y)
                || isBlocked(map, destination.x, destination.y)) {
            return null;
        }

        Queue<Point> queue1 = new ArrayDeque<>();
        Queue<Point> queue2 = new ArrayDeque<>();

        queue1.add(position);

        map[position.y][position.x] = -1;

        for (int i = 2; !queue1.isEmpty(); i++) {
            if (queue1.size() >= map.length * map[0].length) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Map overload");
            }

            for (Point point : queue1) {
                if (point.x == destination.x && point.y == destination.y) {
                    return arrived(map, i - 1, point);
                }

                final Queue<Point> finalQueue = queue2;
                final int finalStepCount = i;

                lookAround(map, point, (x, y) -> {
                    if (isBlocked(map, x, y)) {
                        return;
                    }

                    Point e = new Point(x, y);

                    finalQueue.add(e);

                    map[e.y][e.x] = -finalStepCount;
                });
            }

            if (DEBUG) {
                printMap(map);
            }

            queue1 = queue2;
            queue2 = new ArrayDeque<>();
        }

        resetMap(map);

        return null;
    }

    private static boolean isOutOfMap(final int[][] map,
                                      final int x,
                                      final int y) {
        return x < 0 || y < 0 || map.length <= y || map[0].length <= x;
    }

    private boolean isBlocked(final int[][] map, final int x, final int y) {
        final int i = map[y][x];
        return i < 0 || i == 1;
    }

    private Point[] arrived(final int[][] map, final int size, final Point p) {
        final Point[] optimalPath = new Point[size];

        computeSolution(map, p.x, p.y, size, optimalPath);

        resetMap(map);

        return optimalPath;
    }

    private void resetMap(final int[][] map) {
        for (int y = 0; y < map.length; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < map[0].length; x++) {
                if (map[y][x] < 0) {
                    map[y][x] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void printMap(final int[][] map) {
        for (final int[] r : map) {
            for (final int i : r) {
                System.out.print(i + "\t");
            }

            System.out.println();
        }

        System.out.println("****************************************");
    }

    private void computeSolution(final int[][] map,
                                 final int x,
                                 final int y,
                                 final int stepCount,
                                 final Point[] optimalPath) {
        if (isOutOfMap(map, x, y)
                || map[y][x] == 0
                || map[y][x] != -stepCount) {
            return;
        }

        final Point p = new Point(x, y);

        optimalPath[stepCount - 1] = p;

        lookAround(map, p, (x1, y1) -> computeSolution(map, x1, y1, stepCount - 1, optimalPath));
    }

    private void lookAround(final int[][] map,
                            final Point p,
                            final Callback callback) {
        callback.look(map, p.x + 1, p.y + 1);
        callback.look(map, p.x - 1, p.y + 1);
        callback.look(map, p.x - 1, p.y - 1);
        callback.look(map, p.x + 1, p.y - 1);
        callback.look(map, p.x + 1, p.y);
        callback.look(map, p.x - 1, p.y);
        callback.look(map, p.x, p.y + 1);
        callback.look(map, p.x, p.y - 1);
    }

    private interface Callback {
        default void look(final int[][] map, final int x, final int y) {
            if (isOutOfMap(map, x, y)) {
                return;
            }
            onLook(x, y);
        }

        void onLook(int x, int y);
    }
}
```